# Multiplication of non-negative integers using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, integer

I wanted to execute this piece of code.The question was:
Multiplication of non-negative integers can be defined recursively in terms of addition:

```
mult(n,0)=0
mult(n,m+1)=n+mult(n,m)
```

Write a class which has a method mult which implements such a function...
But,when I run the file,I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at javaapplication56.JavaApplication56.main(JavaApplication56.java:20)
Java Result: 1
```

I am really not sure whats wrong... 
=(

```
package javaapplication56;


public class JavaApplication56 {

    static int mult(int n,int m){
    if (m==0)return 0;
    else return n+mult(n,m-1);
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.print(mult(Integer.parseInt(args[0]),Integer.parseInt(args[1])));

    }

}
```

Comment: how did you run this?did you parse arguments ?

Comment: I just clicked on the run file @FastSnail

Comment: am i supposed to do something else?

Comment: do you know what is `args[0]` ? what is your ide .what is the values you want to parse to `mult(int n,int m)` method .

Comment: @FastSnail OMG i just understood...I'm supposed to do an extra step of passing the argument by writing into the box...Thanks!!

Comment: for testing you can also pass like `mult(20,10);` without parsing commandline arguments

Comment: ohh okies!@FastSnail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**args** parameter in main method is an array of `launch arguments`.

You must execute your class with two arguments to let it work.
e.g.:

`java package.to.your.Class 23 2`

or configure program arguments in your IDE.